# Open Source & Free Adhoc / End User Reporting Tool

Tags: reporting, adhoc-queries

I am looking for an Open Source & Free Browser based Adhoc / End User Reporting Tool preferably based on Java (any other technologies are also welcome).

I have researched on JasperServer Pro, BIRT & Pentaho. Even though these are open source & free, the end user/adhoc reporting components needs to be paid annual license fees which is not quite affordable for us. So please tell you suggestions

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: I did some research recently, it seems that with [Dynamic Reports](http://www.dynamicreports.org/) you can implement some ad hoc functionality rather quickly. http://www.dynamicreports.org/examples/adhoccustomizerreport

Answer (score 4):

Mhm ... I'll throw in a paid one: **[i-net Clear Reports](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystal-clear)** (used to be i-net Crystal-Clear). The reason I do this is simple: I think it fits your needs, but it's a one time investment if you're happy with what it offers. Its constantly being improved and the support is much better than of the most open source or free communities (that should be taken into account).

The product is entirely Java. It has a powerful ad-hoc reporting component that is made to be an easy-to-use thing for non-technical users. Your users won't have to know anything about reporting at all. They simply select the kind of report, the data et voila there is a report suiting the needs.

The reporting server has a great web GUI for ad hoc reporting (and much more), but you could also access a Java applet.

The end users will not need any training since the GUI is highly intuitive. All reports (depending on security settings) can be accessed via DAV our a report repository gui.
The server supports different security settings on a per user or per group basis.

Disclosure: Yep. I work for the company who built this.

Comment: Then I'm filing a bug report here. If you try to access the datasource tab in the online demo, it requires authentication which can not be cancelled without closing the browser/tab. Made me stop looking at the product automatically.

Comment: Thanks. The current version is in its beta stage and we're working hard on it. But I can tell you that we've found and resolved the issue. I hope you'll have another look sometime soon.

Answer (score 1):

[fyireporting](http://www.fyireporting.com/index.html) has a report editor component and is licensed under the Apache v2 License. I still have to do an in-depth evaluation, but it looks quite good from the website.